# Mod_Rewrite not working when i add a query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following rewrite rule in my .htaccess file, but whenever i add parameters to the string it makes the rewrite fail

```
RewriteRule ^c([0-9]+)/[a-zA-z0-9\-]+$ category.php?id=$1 [L]
```

For example:

If i go to the following, all works fine:

```
c87/newest-post
```

But if i go to:

```
c87/newest-post?param1=this&param2=that
c87/newest-post/?param1=this&param2=that
```

it redirects incorrectly and fails. I think it has something to do with the QSA tag, but with my poor knowledge of redirects i cant see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag is required since you have specified a query string in the replacement URL:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.

For the trailing slash you need an extra tweak. The suggested RewriteRule is:

```
RewriteRule ^c([0-9]+)/[a-zA-z0-9\-]+/?$ category.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
# c87/newest-post?param1=this&param2=that  -> category.php?id=87&param1=this&param2=that
# c87/newest-post/?param1=this&param2=that -> category.php?id=87&param1=this&param2=that
```